# QML tab occasionally stretches off-screen

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols

I have a QML-based GUI with a fixed width that uses the `TabView` type in several places.

On one page, I have something like this (leaving out most properties except for lateral anchors):

```
ColumnLayout {
    MyTabsViewSubmenu { // defined below
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Tab { 
            id: someId
            title: someString
            anchors.fill: parent

            SomeCustomClass {
                id: someId2
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }

        // three more tabs defined the same way, with the same anchors...

    }

    // another item below the tabs...
}
```

`MyTabsViewSubmenu` is something like this:

```
TabView {
    Rectanble {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    style: TabViewStyle {
        // miscellaneous style stuff
    }
}
```

One of my four tabs in the `ColumnLayout` above sometimes stretches off the screen when selected. As far as I can tell, there is *nothing* special about it compared to the other items used as tabs throughout the GUI. The layout of this tab is something like this:

```
Item {
    MyTabsViewSubmenu {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: sibling.top

        Tab {
            // no anchors (see below)
            SomeItem {
                anchors.fill: parent
        }
        // ... other tabs....
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: sibling
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        // ... stuff....
    }
}
```

The *entire page* stretches off the screen: both the sub-tab content and the content in the `Rectangle` I've shown here as `sibling`.

I would suspect that possibly the missing `anchors.fill: parent` in the innermost `Tab`s might be the problem, except that `sibling` is *not* (as far as I can tell* missing any anchors, and I've never seen the tabs stretched offscreen without the `sibling` being stretched offscreen as well.

It seems entirely unpredictable whether the stretching occurs or the layout is done correctly. Once the layout has stretched off the screen, I can sometimes get it to correct itself by navigating away from that page and back.

I'm using Qt 5.6.1-1 on Debian 7.

**EDIT:** When I navigate to the "stretched" tab and the bug occurs causing the stretching, the *tabs themselves* at the top of the page *also* get "stretched" somewhat. Returning to a different tab un-stretches the tabs.

Comment: Consider creating a minimal standalone example that reproduces the problem. We can't try the code, because it has external references and missing parts. Very often, stripping out parts of your application in the process of creating a minimal example makes you realize where the problem is. In general, creating a minimal example is time well spent, because then you can get better help, and in case it turns out to be a bug in the framework, you can simply use it as a testcase for reporting the bug. At that point a missing testcase will significantly reduce the chances of the bug being resolved.

Comment: @jpnurmi I'd love to, but if my description and code snippets above aren't enough to trigger the bug, I frankly have nothing  else I can even think to look at as a possible culprit; it's a big app. Even with the full app, the bug is rare enough that it's hard to reproduce, so once I have a minimized example, I won't know if it actually triggers the bug unless I manage to trigger it. My biggest hope for this question at the moment is that someone either (1) has happened to see a similar issue before and knows what to look for to debug it, or (2) knows why anchors might be insufficient here.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I've never been able to tame the `ColumnLayout` when `Layout.fillWidth: true`. Try setting the `Layout.maximumWidth` to something in-between the normal and infinity, so we'll see if it's limited by this value.

Comment: @Velkan Setting `Layout.maximumWidth` appears to do the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### The fix

Setting `Layout.maximumWidth` (as per Velkan's comment) appears to resolve the issue. Additionally, it appears to make the page load faster.

#### Observations and testing

It's now about a week and a half since I introduced this change to the code, and the product has been heavily tested since then.

We have discovered a second component that needs `Layout.maximumWidth` set in order to keep from stretching off the screen, and indeed applying this fix to both the original problematic components has prevented the screen-stretching bug. So this is definitely a valid fix.

#### Possible root cause (i.e. groundless speculation)

I suspect that the QML engine attempts to size "Layout" objects by starting with the maximum width, then shrinking them to fit (or something like this). If the maximum width is unset, it's set to something like "infinity". Without a `maximumWidth`, it appears that the auto-shrinking operation sometimes fails, leaving the component stretched offscreen. I suspect that the automatic-resizing code may be impacted by some kind of nondeterminism in the order in which the sizes of different QML components are computed.